# Getting * BSTR result from unmanaged dll using C#

Tags: c#, dll

I define function to call like

```
   [DllImport("LFWAttend.dll")]      
    public static extern int FK_GetPhotoDataWithString(int nHandleIndex, int vEnrollNumber,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]ref string fstrEnrollData);
```

by using 
[this manual.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC8DW.jpg) (Don't worry that it's in Chinese. I only need the definition part)

And then I call the function like this

```
    string test="";
    Module.FK_GetPhotoDataWithString(connectId, id, ref test);
```

In the manual, it said that the function will send string back in "test". But when the code run to the function call path, the debugger exists.
I built it in Visual Studio and got nothing. There was no error and exception.
I do very confuse with Marchaling concept too. Please help.

Comment: Don't post *screenshots* of code, and don't post documentation in *Chinese* (do you seriously expect most people here to understand it?). Paste the first into the post, and translate the second.

Comment: The function has a return type, but you are not storing it anywhere or doing anything with it afterwards. Another thing, in your "manual" it seems to have a return type of `long` but your definition is `public static extern int`.

Comment: @Keyur That return path is not matter. the problem is at getting ref string path.

Comment: *int* is fine, it matches *long*.  First try adding the [In,Out] attributes to the string parameter to tell the marshaller that it needs to copy the string back.  If that still doesn't work then next consider using Marshal.StringToBSTR() and declaring the argument `ref IntPtr`.  Then Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR() and Marshal.FreeBSTR() after the call.  And *do* check the return value, you need to identify failure.

Comment: @HansPassant Does not work both. The debugger existed before I can watch the function result or the string parameter. :(

Comment: Your English is difficult to comprehend, I'd have to assume you meant "exited".  Which is just another word for "my program crashed".  Look in the Output window for the process exit code.  Native code can easily make a program crash to the desktop without a diagnostic.  You did not post the [DllImport] declaration you used, getting the CallingConvention or CharSet wrong is an easy way to trigger such a crash.

Comment: @HansPassant [DllImport] declaration updated.  It exited with code 0xc0000374 (I googled and it's heap problem). I'm sorry for bad english.